# T-SQL compound index sufficient for query on subset of columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, database-performance, compound-index

Is a compound index sufficient for queries against a subset of columns ?

```
CREATE TABLE [FILE_STATUS_HISTORY]
(
    [FILE_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [STATUS_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [TIMESTAMP_UTC] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FILE_STATUS_HISTORY] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([FILE_ID] ASC, [STATUS_ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FILE_STATUS_HISTORY] 
ON [FILE_STATUS_HISTORY] ([FILE_ID] ASC,
                          [STATUS_ID] ASC,
                          [TIMESTAMP_UTC] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM [FILE_STATUS_HISTORY]
WHERE [FILE_ID] = 382748
ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP_UTC] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

A composite index on `( File_Id, Timestamp_UTC desc )` should optimize handling the `where` and `top`/`order by` clauses. The *actual execution plan* will show whether the query optimizer agrees.

A [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/) would also have `Status_Id` as an [included column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) so that the index could satisfy the entire query in a single lookup.